# how to create values for a new column for each key based on a condition Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark

I have some data as follows, which I have read into a usual Spark RDD (with no Schema):

[image: before transformation]

Now, I 'd like to create a new column. The new column will be set to 1 for each customer if the events for a customer includes w as a value. So the resulting RDD will be:

[image: after treansformation]

I haven't been able to do this. What I have so far is the following, where data1 is the data read into an RDD:

```
val data2 = data1.groupBy(_._2)
  .map(_._2.map{ case (a1: Array[String],   a2, a3, a4) =>
    val myString  = "w"
    if (a1.contains(myString)) { (a1,a2,a3,a4,array_of_ones) else (a1,a2,a3,a4,array_of_zeros)}
       })
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bTx.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bTx.jpgenter code here

In the above, array_of_ones and array_of_zeros must have the same length as a1 for every partition. How can I do this? If possible, please assume joining RDDs are not allowed. Thank you.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you want. Customer 3 has no `w` but some ones in indicator3. Also, could post actual data structures with correct types instead of screenshots? Types matter.. Finally join has pretty much the same performance as groupBy. Not that it is required.

Comment: I am sorry about this. Indicator3 must have 0s for customer 3 and 1s for customer 4. Types are string for event and customers, Int for the indicators. I read the data into a tuple (a1, a2,a3,a4) . I'll update the question in 2 days. My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize but please do correct this :)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is to use `DataFrames`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

val df = data1.toDF("event", "customer", "indicator1", "indicator2")
val w = Window.partitionBy($"customer").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)

val isW = ($"event" === "w").cast("long")
val indicator3 = (sum(isW).over(w) > 0).cast("long")

df.withColumn("indicator3", indicator3)
```